# improve deployment time of yocto based development

Tags: deployment, build, yocto

In our company we have switched to Linux embedded systems (2 different platforms). Our build is based on yocto.
Unfortunately we are all quite unexperienced with it. Especially I have some questions about collaboration within yocto and with reusing its deployment (SDK).

In our company there are multiple teams involved in development:

1. Team1: Maintaining yocto and the Linux base system
2. Team2: Developing company-own libraries which will become part of the base system (own git repository, which is added in yocto recipe)
3. Team3: Developing software (based on Linux base system + company-own libraries)

The problem: Our current development workflow is quite slow.

**For example:** 
There is some bug in a small company-own library LibA.

- Team2 commits some bugfix for LibA (small project, a standalone build would take ~2min).
- In a next step there has to be a Pull-Request updating the CommitID within LibA's yocto recipe (~15min including a small CI build + merge checks).
- As soon as the Pull-Request is merged, a release-build can be triggered (CI). The result of this build is a SDK and a MfgTool (~120min for all platforms/variants).
- Now Team3 has to download the new SDK and update their build to use the new SDK (~5min).
- Then they trigger a release build of their software (~10min) which results in a flashable image.

So all in all a small change of LibA takes about 2 hours until it can be integrated by Team3, and another 15min for the complete software to be available to our test team.

- What is the recommended standard way for this (I think we are not the only company with this issue)?
  How can we improve the yocto build workflow?
- Is there any way to prevent that the yocto build must be used if LibA changes?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: We have the same kind of workflow, maybe using extensible [eSDK](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#sdk-extensible) reduces integration duration?

Comment: Hi @Totschi if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I would takle your main issue, the build time of 120m seems very long.

I would recommend to create use [Source Mirror](https://wiki.yoctoproject.org/wiki/How_do_I#Q:_How_do_I_create_my_own_source_download_mirror_.3F) ,  [sstate mirror](https://wiki.yoctoproject.org/wiki/Enable_sstate_cache). Do one buildjob in the night which creates those contents. Take a build machine with at least 8 cores and 16-32GB ram.